# Can't start neo4j on mac

Tags: macos, neo4j

When I am trying to start `neo4j` on `macOS Sierra 10.12.6` it can not start because port `7687` is already in use. The port is showing to be free, nothing is running there: I checked it with:

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep 7687
```

and also

```
sudo lsof -i :7687
```

So, I tried to find running processes by `ps aux | grep java` and `ps aux | grep neo4j` and found one process for each, the id of which is constantly updating, so I can not just kill it. I found the following thread on `stackoverflow` that deals with similar issue:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333373/kill-process-when-pid-is-constantly-changing

However, unfortunately the provided solution gives no parent processes. I ran the command `pgrep mtp | while read line; do ps -p $line -o ppid; done` and it gave empty response. The other command: `pgrep mtp | xargs -i pstree -ps {}` gives error message that `xargs` is used improperly. I also tried the following:

```
ps aux | pgrep neo4j
ps aux | pgrep java
```

with no success. I also tried to use 'neo4j' and 'java' in quotation marks, but no luck. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues. First one was that the version of the `neo4j` database that created the database was different from the version that I was trying to run it with. Another issue was that I should have started `neo4j` with `./neo4j console`, not `./neo4j start` on `macOS`. I am working with several computers with different `OS`, that's why faced the issue.